# Lync Chat From Command Line

Tags: lync

I'm trying to start a Lync IM session from the command line. I have Lync running. If I use:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\lync.exe" sip:user@address.com
```

It works, but it also opens up the Lync window. I want it to just start the IM session without bringing up the Lync window as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ start sip:abc@abc.com
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.